# Cannot use PagerSlidingTabStrip as library project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-library, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to include [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) in my application project. But I cannot. After I added PagerSlidingTabStrip library project to my application project, I found that I cannot use it so I checked my project properties->android. The Library project I just added show "X" red mark.

Here is step I used to include `PagerSlidingTabStrip`

**Import PagerSlidingTabStrip to eclipse**

- File->Import->Existing Android code into Workspace
- click browse and navigated to ..\PagerSlidingTabStrip-master\library
- then changed the project name to "Lib_PagerSlidingTabStrip"
- finish
- now I have PagerSlidingTabStrip in my workspace.

**Include PagerSlidingTabStrip to my application project**

- Right click on my project name -> properties->android
- in library section add Lib_PagerSlidingTabStrip
- then click ok

and here is a picture of properties->android
[image]

Why is this happen? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK now I know what cause me the problem. this is because my

```
eclipse workspace is in drive D: 
but library project is in drive C:
```

So when import library into eclipse make sure you check **"Copy projects into workspace"** and finish. Then re-add library project to application project again.